# One-dimensional linear interpolation with MKL

Tags: intel-mkl

I'm new to MKL and I have this Python code that I want to convert in a C++ code that makes use of the MKL function "dfdInterpolate1D" (https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-df-interpolate1d-df-interpolateex1d). The only example I found is this https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-data-fitting-usage-examples but it's a Cubic Spline-Based interpolation and the API is quite intimidating. I have already coded a simple function that imitates numpy.interp but I need something optimized.

```
stokes = np.arange(0,len(raw1660))
antistokes = stokes*(1+walkOff/1000)
raw1450 = np.interp(stokes,antistokes,raw1450)
```

Comment: `numpy.interp` doesn't use MKL functionality - it maps to the function `arr_interp`(https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/3d31770c61ea2412267c233d38ccc33d5d3a0610/numpy/core/src/multiarray/compiled_base.c#L484)

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at the `interpolate1D` examples for C API. Check the `MKLROOT\examples\datafittingc\source` folder - you may see there the following `dfdInterpolate1D` examples:

- `dfdcubicspline_interp.c`
- `dfdfifthorderspline_interp.c`
- `dfdhermitecubicspline.c`
- `dfdhymancubic.c`
- `dfdinterpusercells.c`
- `dfdlookup_interp.c`
- `dfdquadraticspline.c`
- `dfdstepwise_interp.c`

Comment: I didn't found a straightforward example to perform a simple 1D interpolation, I have already tested dfdstepwise_interp.c, dfdlookup_interp.c, dfdlinearspline.c but I don't understand them.

Comment: then what do you mean by straightforward example to perform a simple 1D interpolation?   what kind of splines are you trying to solve?

Comment: You may also ask the same question to the intel mkl software forum follow this link:https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-math-kernel-library.

Comment: I just want to do the same thing as numpy.interp !

Comment: then look at numpy doc and realize what exactly numpy.interp does and map this option to the mkl df API